# When class injected by RoboGuice @Inject could be null?

Tags: java, android, guice, inject, roboguice

When roboguice's `@Inject` could be null?

I have class:

```
@Singleton
public class MyClass extends AnotherClass{ ...
```

In many places I'm using

```
@Inject private MyClass mMyClass;
```

and it is working correctly.

Recently I wrote simple class handling events from event bus. This class is created and registered in main ui thread. In this class I'm injecting `MyClass` same way like other places, but it is `null` now.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ...
    mMyHandler = new MyHandler(this);
    mMyEventBus.register(mMyHandler);

public class MyHandler{
    private final Context mContext;

    public MyHandler(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Inject private MyClass mMyClass;

    public void onEventBackgroundThread(MyEvent event) {
        mMyClass.someMethod; //mMyClass is null
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm using RoboGuice 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RoboGuice has no chance to inject anything into your `MyHandler` instance because you are using `new` to create it, instead of having it created by your DI framework. I'm not familiar with RoboGuice (only plain Guice), but probably there there is a way to ask the injector to inject members after you created the instance by yourself. Though I think it's better to restucture the code so the instance is created by RoboGuice in the first place.